# jQuery: ajax and autocomplete fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to combine ajax request with an autocomplete function. But it seems something is wrong for the autocomplete. I am using [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to implement my code.

**The console gives me back something like : `http://domain.com/[%22...array from ajax here]?term=What i put in my input`** pointing a 403 error -.-

I am a bit lost though it seemed simple to me.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      $("input[name=search]").on('keyup', function(){
         jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'POST', // Le type de ma requete
           <?php echo "url: '".PTC.ROOT.DS."ajax'"; ?>, // URL to call (works)
           data: {
             search: ''+$("input[name=search]").val()+''
           }, 
           success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

             window.availableNames = data; //JSON format
             $(function() {
              alert(window.availableNames); //Show the JSON encoded table with the right result.

              $("input[name=search]").autocomplete({source: window.availableNames}); // Fails.
             });
           },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           }
         });
      });
      </script>
```

Thank you

EDIT : Separately Ajax works, and Autocomplete works. But when I try to incorporate the second in the first, it doest.

Comment: Is this page running on the same domain as the page you are calling via AJAX? i.e. they are both on `domain.com`, not different domains or sub-domains?

Comment: Just a quick one - if you're using FireFox, this could be fixed by: `SecFilterEngine Off` in your .htaccess :)

Comment: yes, it is the same domain !
@Jimbo I use Chrome :s

Comment: Try accessing the url directly, your file probably does not have the right permissions.

Comment: Well, the ajax stuff works fine : it goes in database, and gives back something like ["name surname, name1 surname1"] But it does not want to be used by autocomplete and instead the console returns something weird :/

Comment: `pointing a 403 error`, means you have don't have permissions to access the url. So, the url should not be doing what you expect it to.

Comment: I agree, as you can see above, I call `ajax.php` on my domain but `jquery-latest.min.js:3` calls a random URL made as I described...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete has the option to provide an url as [the source-parameter](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Autocomplete#overview)

> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead the request parameter "term" gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

So make sure the api endpoint located at the supplied url returns json and reacts correctly to the 'term' parameter.

This way you don't have to fiddle with your own ajax calls.

So you autocomplete code would look something like this:

```
$("input[name=search]").autocomplete({source: '<?php echo PTC.ROOT.DS."ajax"; ?>'});
```